# Stop a script after a given time in Unix bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script which is runnnig another script. What i want is something like this :

```
#in scriptA.sh
./scriptB 
wait 10 seconds and kill scriptB
```

Is it doable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./scriptB &
sleep 10s
kill $!
```

#### How it works

- `./scriptB &`

  This starts `scriptB` in the background.
- `sleep 10s`

  This waits 10 seconds
- `kill $!`

  This kills the most recently executed background process.

  `kill` will kill any process given is process ID.  `$!` is the process ID of the most recently executed background process.